# Altair: encoding field is specified without a type

Tags: python, pandas, altair

Hi my gorgeous friend on the Internet,
I have a question about how to plot a Chart in Altair.

I have been struggling with this error since yesterday and still haven't plotted successfully.

I first imported some modules and data,

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy as np

url = "https://github.com/byuidatascience/data4missing/raw/master/data-raw/flights_missing/flights_missing.json"
flights = pd.read_json(url)
flights.head()
```

Then, I used groupby() to add all num_of_total_flights together for each airport_code.

```py
ttl = flights.groupby('airport_code')['num_of_flights_total'].sum()
ttl
```

After I checked ttl was fine, I wanted to plot the chart.

```py
alt.Chart(ttl).mark_bar().encode(
    y="airport_code",
    x="num_of_flights_total",
)
```

Then I got this error message: num_of_flights_total encoding field is specified without a type; the type cannot be automatically inferred because the data is not specified as a pandas.DataFrame.

Does anyone know how to solve this??
Thanks for your valuable time in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello there charismatic stranger, I have an answer to your question. The error message is misleading in this case (and will likely be [improved in the nearish future](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2584)). Because `.groupby().sum()` returns as series, you need to reset the index to get `airport_code` as a column name:

```py
ttl = flights.groupby('airport_code')['num_of_flights_total'].sum().reset_index()

alt.Chart(ttl).mark_bar().encode(
    y="airport_code",
    x="num_of_flights_total",
)
```

[image]